# Permutations of combinations of two groups

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

In C#, I am attempting to write an algorithm to balance two teams given integer player ratings for each of the players.

The data set looks like this:

```
Player 1:  1330
Player 2:  1213
Player 3:  1391
Player 4:  1192
Player 5:  1261
Player 6:  1273
Player 7:  1178
Player 8:  1380
Player 8:  1200
Player 10: 1252
```

I'd like to build two sets of five players, where the **total** rating difference of both teams is as small as possible, for a fair match.

Now to do this I'd like to generate all team permutations (each permutation is two teams of 5 players). But all c# permutation examples are for combining things like power sets, not teams.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), not permutations. Using the standard formula we know that there are 252 possible combinations of 10 players taken 5 at a time. There's a really easy way to generate the combinations, which vib mentioned in his answer and I expand on here.

There are 10 players. If you view the players as a 10-bit number, then each player corresponds to a bit in that number. Any 10-bit number that has exactly 5 bits set is a valid team. So `0101010101` is a valid team, but `0011000100` is not a valid team.

In addition, any valid team has exactly one opposing team. That is, given 10 players and a team of 5 members, then there are only 5 other people to select. So team `0101010101` is paired with team `1010101010`.

2^10 is 1024. So we only have to check 1024 possible combinations. Actually, we only have to check 512 because we know that any team with a number above 511 will have the highest numbered player on it (i.e. the last bit is set), and any number less than 512 will not have that player on it.

So the idea is, for each number less than 512:

1. if there are not five bits set in the number, go to the next one
2. invert the number. This will give you the opposing team
3. Calculate the ratings for the team and the opposing team

Simple C# code to do that:

```
private readonly int[] _playerRatings = new[] {1330, 1213, 1391, 1192, 1261, 1273, 1178, 1380, 1200, 1252};

private int CalculateTeamScore(int team)
{
    var score = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if ((team & 1) == 1)
        {
            score += _playerRatings[i];
        }
        team >>= 1;
    }
    return score;
}

private bool IsValidTeam(int team)
{
    // determine how many bits are set, and return true if the result is 5
    // This is the slow way, but it works.
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if ((team & 1) == 1)
        {
            ++count;
        }
        team >>= 1;
    }
    return (count == 5);
}

public void Test()
{
    // There are 10 players. You want 5-player teams.

    // Assign each player a bit position in a 10-bit number.
    // 2^10 is 1024.
    // Start counting at 0, and whenever you see a number that has 5 bits set,
    // you have a valid 5-player team.
    // If you invert the bits, you get the opposing team.

    // You only have to count up to 511 (2^9 - 1), because any team after that
    // will already have been found as the opposing team.

    for (var team = 0; team < 512; ++team)
    {
        if (IsValidTeam(team))
        {
            var opposingTeam = ~team;
            var teamScore = CalculateTeamScore(team);
            var opposingTeamScore = CalculateTeamScore(opposingTeam);
            var scoreDiff = Math.Abs(teamScore - opposingTeamScore);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} - {2}:{3} - Diff = {4}.", 
                team, teamScore, opposingTeam, opposingTeamScore, scoreDiff);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to provide the code that extracts the player numbers from the team number. It's a simple matter of outputting the bit number from the set bits. You can modify the score computation code to do that.

Note that the code I used to find how many bits are set is not at all optimum. But it works. If you want a faster way, check out the [BitHacks page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive), which has many different ways.

Comment: Jim, I implemented it here: https://github.com/paralin/BalanceAlgorithm/ - you had some critical errors in your code (using `-` instead of `~` and signed integers) that you might want to fix in your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChristianStewart: My code has `~` where it belongs. I see what you mean about the signed integers, although the algorithm should still work. The opposing team numbers will be negative, which is kind of wonky. That's easily fixed by writing `var opposingTeam = (~team) & 0x3FF;` In any event, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: The problem with the code you wrote was that because it's a signed integer the first player in the list is always on the first team. Also I saw  lot of cases where players would appear on both teams for some odd reason. it works better with unsigned ints I think :)

Comment: @ChristianStewart: I'm not sure what you mean. I ran my code exactly as written above, and it produces correct results. The first player is not always on the first team. For example, team 62 (0000111110) doesn't have that player. There are plenty of other examples. The last player (with the rating of 1252) is always on the opposing team, but that's okay. All combinations are still represented. Also, the only problem with the signed integers is that the opposing team numbers are displayed as negative numbers. The `& 0x3ff` change that I showed in my previous comment fixes that.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Check your code. Your loop is using `team < Math.Pow(2, PlayerPool.Length)-1)` So it's checking teams 0 through 1022. That is, it's doing more comparisons than it needs to, and it's missing the last one. It's checking team 31 against its opposing team (which would be -32 in my code), and then later it's checking team -32 against team 31. No need to do both checks. If you use the condition `team < (1 << (PlayerPool.Length - 1))`, it will check 0 through 511, which is what my code does. That's the same as `Math.Pow(2, PlayerPool.Length-1)`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see. I think I must have translated your code somehow wrong in there. I don't see how making a signed integer negative does anything but flip the first bit though.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Using 8-bit signed integers, the number 1 is binary 00000001. -1 is 11111111. Using two's complement representation, you make a number negative by complementing the value and adding 1. So `~1` is 11111110. You add 1 and you get 11111111.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to generate all permutations. Look at all integers i between 0 and 2^10-1 and look at how many bits of the integer are set to one. Whenever this is 5 this gives you a valid partition of your 10 teams in two group of five.

Comment: Is "bites" supposed to be "bits" or "bytes"?

Comment: it would be helpful to give the reasoning behind this method

Answer (score 1):

you could use Linq to solve your issue

in this example it is two teams of two persons

using my understanding of [Jim Mischel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29832520/40868)

[.net fiddler run](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qL4O87)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Player
    {
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public int PlayerBit { get; set; }
        public int PlayerScore { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Player: {0} Score: {1}\n",PlayerId,PlayerScore);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int maxDiff = 15;

            var players = new List<Player> { new Player() {PlayerId = 1, PlayerBit = 1<<0, PlayerScore = 1330},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 2, PlayerBit = 1<<1, PlayerScore = 1213},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 3, PlayerBit = 1<<2, PlayerScore = 1391},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 4, PlayerBit = 1<<3, PlayerScore = 1192},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 5, PlayerBit = 1<<4, PlayerScore = 1261},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 6, PlayerBit = 1<<5, PlayerScore = 1273},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 7, PlayerBit = 1<<6, PlayerScore = 1178},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 8, PlayerBit = 1<<7, PlayerScore = 1380},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 9, PlayerBit = 1<<8, PlayerScore = 1200},
                                             new Player() {PlayerId = 10, PlayerBit = 1<<9, PlayerScore = 1252}};

            var maxTeam = players.Max(x => x.PlayerBit);
            var maxBit = maxTeam * 2 - 1;

            var team = from t1 in Enumerable.Range(0, maxTeam) where getBitCount(t1) == 5 select t1;

            var match = team.Select(x => new { t1 = x, t2 = maxBit - x });

            foreach (var m in match)
            {
                var t1 = players.Where(x => (x.PlayerBit & m.t1) == x.PlayerBit);
                var t2 = players.Where(x => (x.PlayerBit & m.t2) == x.PlayerBit);
                var t1Score = t1.Sum(x => x.PlayerScore);
                var t2Score = t2.Sum(x => x.PlayerScore);

                if (Math.Abs(t1Score - t2Score) < maxDiff)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Team 1 total score {0} Team 2 total score {1}", t1Score, t2Score);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} versu \n{1}\n\n", string.Join("", t1.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()), string.Join("", t2.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
                }
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static int getBitCount(int bits)
        {
            bits = bits - ((bits >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            bits = (bits & 0x33333333) + ((bits >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            return ((bits + (bits >> 4) & 0xf0f0f0f) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not it at all. How are you creating teams with 5 players each?  And you initialize `maxDiff` to 1, which could prevent you from getting any results at all. I'll have to post my code.

Comment: @JimMischel, at diff =1, i get 71 "match" with teams of 2 players which is a lot in itself.

Comment: But if `maxDiff == 1`, how does `Math.Abs(t1.totalScore - t2.totalScore) <= maxDiff` ever evaluate to true? 71 certainly isn't smaller than 1. Are you sure that the code you posted is actually the code you're running?

Comment: @JimMischel, yes. I will put it on a online place where it get run, while i do that you can run it yourself to check

Comment: @JimMischel, link put in my answer to see the result

Comment: And if you examine your output, the only items output are those that have a difference of 1 or 0. Look at the difference between t1.totalScore and t2.totalScore in your outputs.

Comment: @JimMischel, read the question, he want to make match where there is a small difference between team to be "fair", this is my implementation of being fair

Comment: And if there was no team combination that had a difference of 1, then you'd get no output. Before he mentions fair, he says, "as small as possible." In addition, you have duplicate outputs. That is, you have a team in which player 1 is #6 and player 2 is #9. Later, you have player 1 is #9 and player 2 is #6. You're comparing each team paring twice. You should remove those duplicates because when you expand to 5-player teams you'll more than just duplicate the pairings. The basic problem is that you're generating permutations rather than combinations.

Comment: @JimMischel, you are right, now I did a major change and now i do team of 5 with proper combinations

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the optimized version of [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is NP-hard

However as n = 10 which is pretty small, you can still find all permutation and find the answer, for larger n, you may use a quick and easy-to-implement greedy approximation which shows on the wiki-page too. Below I only show a sample code with brute force n = 10 case to find the answer. Though it is written in C++, nothing special inside and all operators / array are the same in C#, you should do the translation job yourself, complexity is O(2^10 * 10)

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int a[10] = {1330,1213,1391,1192,1261,1273,1178,1380,1200,1252};
vector<int> team1, team2;
int ans = 1<<28, T1, T2;

int bits(int x){
 int cnt = 0; 
 while(x){ cnt += x&1; x>>=1;}
 return cnt;
}

int main(){
 for(int i=0; i< 1<<10; i++){
  if(bits(i) == 5){
   int t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
   for(int x = i,y=(1<<10)-1-i, j=0; x; x>>=1,y>>=1, j++) {
    t1 += (x&1)*a[j];
    t2 += (y&1)*a[j];
   }
   if(ans > abs(t1-t2)){ ans = abs(t1-t2); T1 = i; T2 = (1<<10)-1-i;}
  }
 }
 for(int i=1; T1 || T2; T1>>=1, T2>>=1, i++) {
  if(T1&1) team1.push_back(i);
  if(T2&1) team2.push_back(i);
 }
 printf("Team 1: ");
 for(int i=0; i<5;i++) printf("%d ", team1[i]); 
 puts("");
 printf("Team 2: ");
 for(int i=0; i<5;i++) printf("%d ", team2[i]); 
 puts("");
 printf("Difference: %d\n", ans);
 return 0;
}
```